# SoapUI (non pro) Property Transfer getting the basics going using XPath

Tags: xpath, soap, soapui

Preamble: First off - I am a complete novice, and have zero clue what I am doing, apologies in advance.
Question:
I have working SOAP messages in SoapUI (regular flavour) that I have valid responses to. I am trying to build a set of test steps that can complete a transaction lifecycle for testing.
I only just figured out that Property Transfer could be used to take a response from call A to be used in call B.
I have the source declared correctly, and the Target correctly, With the default namespace info I have successfully transferred the complete response of call A into the target property. Now I just need to cut that down to one element only. I have tried all manner of things, but I seem to be getting [null] every time (except where I don't include the bit to choose one element at all, as noted above).
I just don't know what the format of the line that specifies the desired field should be. I know I have to have the name of the desired field in it, near the end, but beyond that I am randomly trying all sorts.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have it solved, after many stupid trials and errors. For posterity and so I can reference it myself in future, this is what I got going:
Inside the soap message response body, there is a tag ns1 (which I am guessing is namespace 1).
Inside that is a section called salesInvoiceReturn.
Inside that is another section called salesInvoiceDetails.
Inside that is a field that I need is called salesInvoiceSalesTax.
So my line in the XPath Source section that works reads:
//ns1:salesInvoiceReturn/salesInvoiceDetails/salesInvoiceSalesTax

Pressing the Run button shows me it captures the correct value into the Custom Property I selected. I don't seem to need any code at all in the Target section.